# store files in Neo4j : neostore.nodestore.db

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, datamodel

I'm reading about Neo4j underlying infrastructure in it's book and I think I found a contradiction .Here In the text it is mentioned that :"The next four
bytes represent the ID of the first relationship connected to the node, and the following
four bytes represent the ID of the first property for the node" :[image]

but as you can see in the figure 6-4 :[image] if you look at the photo it is Nextrelid! which one is correct? and if we only store first relationship in the nodestore file, what happen to the other relationship?

Comment: Where is the issue? Look: "The next four bytes represent the ID of the first relationship connected to the node" (`nextRelId`) "and the following four bytes represent the ID of the first property for the node" (`nextPropId`). This is not right?

Comment: Also, about the properties: the Neo4j property store file stores properties in a linked list way. So from the first property you can "jump" to the next following pointers and so on.

Comment: If you quote sections from a book, you should at least provide some kind of link to the book. In this case, it was: [Graph Databases](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/), which is downloadable for free.

Comment: Also, if you just kept reading a couple more paragraphs further, the book mentions linked lists for getting all the relationships (and properties) for a node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the point of view of the node, the next relationship id is the same thing as "the id of the first relationship connected to the node". They're different ways of describing the same thing.

The pattern here is that relationships are stored as a chain. To iterate over all relationships, from the node, you use the id of the first relationship to jump to that relationship in memory, then jump to the area in memory on that relationship where the next rel id is stored and pointer chase across the rest of the chain.

That said, when relationships reach a particular density (I think it's 50 rels per node) then the [structure is somewhat different](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/366d30928d1b1590eba5daef92116ecc15aa36b1), a new entity is present between the node and its relationships to allow for more efficient navigation of its relationships.